# How to send data through PUT to Laravel API from Vue.js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to update the customers table, therefore I made a route in laravel to do so like this:
`Route::put('/api/customers/update/{id}', [CustomerController::class, 'update']);```, The method to update the user is working fine if I make the call to the API from Postman, but if I make a call using axios it won't receive anything. Here is my Axios function:

```
            editCustomer(){

                const data = {
                    name: this.name,
                    surname: this.surname,
                    phone: this.phone,
                    email: this.email
                }

                let customer = JSON.stringify(data);
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('json', customer);

                let url = "api/customers/update/"+this.id;

                axios.put(url, formData)
                    .then(res=>{
                        console.log(res.data.status);
                    })
                    .catch(error=>{
                        console.log(error);
                    });

            }
```

And here is my CustomerController update method:

```
    public function update($id, Request $request) {

        $token = $request->header('Authorization');
        $jwtAuth = new \JwtAuth();
        $checkToken = $jwtAuth->checkToken($token);

        if($checkToken){

            $json = $request->input('json', null);
            $params_array = json_decode($json, true);

            if(!empty($params_array)){
                $validate = \Validator::make($params_array, [
                    'name' => 'alpha',
                    'surname' => 'alpha',
                    'email' => 'email|unique:customers,email,'.$id,
                    'phone' => 'numeric'
                ]);

                if($validate->fails()){
                    $data = array(
                        'status' => 'error',
                        'code' => 400
                    );
                }else{

                    $customer = Customer::find($id);
                    $updated = $customer->update($params_array);

                    if($updated){
                        $data = array(
                            'status' => 'success',
                            'code' => 200
                        );
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $data = array(
                    'status' => 'Data error'
                );
            }
        }else{
            $data = array(
                'status' => 'error'
            );
        }
                 
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

What I'm seeing when I get the res.data.status Object is: `Data error`. Is like the front end is sending nothing. BTW if I `console.log(customer)` I do see it is a valid JSON string. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How is Vue relevant here?

Comment: And have you checked what `$json` is? Have you checked the request in the network tab in devtools?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's network inspector (or better still, Laravel Telescope) to inspect the *actual* body of the PUT request that the browser is sending?

Comment: Hi, I indeed checked the network tab and I see the request URL is correct, request method is set to PUT, and the payload is the actual JSON string. Again, I don't have issues when I make the PUT request through Postman to try the update method.